# method in console.log changes array

Tags: arrays, console.log

Im having a hard time understanding the behavior of this piece of code:

```
var myArray=new Array;
myArray = ["1","2","3","4"];
console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArray.pop());
console.log(myArray);
```

Logging results are:

```
'Array [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ]'
'4'
'Array [ "1", "2", "3" ]'
```

It looks like the `console.log((myArray.pop()))` statement not only displays the value, but is actually doing the 'pop'.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: You are executing the `pop` which changes the array - why are you surprised by this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal behaviour. `pop` removes the last element in the array and returns its value. If you're looking just for the last element without removing it you can do:

```
console.log(myArray[myArray.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method [`arr.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from an array and returns that value to the caller. It returns the removed element from the array; `undefined` if the array is empty. So this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is behaving normally. According to the documentation [Arrays POP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) of MDN. You can see that it clearly states that it will alter the length of the Array. In addition to this, `pop` function returns the removed element that is why `console.log(myArray.pop())` printed `4`. The `pop` methods **remove the last element** and **return that element**.

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly. 
In array, there are two methods for inserting and deleting.
one of them is push() and another is pop().
Normally, push() insert an element from the start where pop() removes the element from the last.
In your case,

```
console.log(myArray.pop()); 
//It is printing out the popped element which is 4. right? so, it's correct.
// It is showing you which item is popped or removed from myArray.
Then,
//your last line of console.log is displaying the array after removing 4.
```